# How do I open multiple pictures using tkinter.filedialog askopenfiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm working on a college research project analyzing images, the particulars don't really matter for this question and I'll leave those parts out for sake of clarity.

My code works **great for single images** but I'm having **trouble with multiple images**. Tkinter doesn't really have good documentation on this and I've been struggling to figure it out.

Here is an example of the working code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

image_formats= [("JPEG", "*.jpg")]
file_path = askopenfile(filetypes=image_formats, initialdir="/", title='Please select a picture to analyze')

image = data.imread(file_path.name)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

This code allows me to click on one image to open in the tkinter menu but **does not allow ctrl-click for multiple images**

If I change every "askopenfile" to "askopenfile**s**" it allows me to ctrl-click multiple images but throws the error:

```
image = data.imread(file_path.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I know I'm going to have to do a loop to open every image but I don't really know what I'm doing wrong or what the right way to do this for multiple images would be.

I'm looking for a fix that will allow **users to ctrl-click multiple images** so that **tkinter** will **grab** the **filepaths** and put them into a **list** for skimage and matplotlib to open (and later analyze).

Sorry if this is too complicated, If you need more explanation or screenshots I'll be more than happy to make an edit so the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the name you should use - `askopenfilenames()` . Example -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

image_formats= [("JPEG", "*.jpg")]
file_path_list = askopenfilenames(filetypes=image_formats, initialdir="/", title='Please select a picture to analyze')

for file_path in file_path_list:
    image = data.imread(file_path)

    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

`askopenfile()` actually opens the file for you and returns that (or `askopenfiles()` opens all files and returns them) . I am not really sure what could be causing `file_path` to become None though.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes the problem!